# What is the basic reproduction number ($R_0$) for a logistic function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A simple function to describe epidemic growth is the logistic function:

$\Large{y=\frac{L}{1+\rm{e}^{-k{x-x_0}}}}$,

where
L is the carrying capacity, namely the maximum value of y,
$x_0$ is the x-value of the sigmoid's inflexion point, and
$k$ is the growth rate.

Another function that is often used gives the basic reproduction number:

$\Large{R_0=1+\frac{T\log{2}}{t_d}}$,

where
T is the infectious period and
$t_d$ is the doubling time.

But what is $R_0$ for the first function? I am not even sure whether it is constant or not. If it is constant, what is it? If it is variable, what is it as a function of x?